# How to get persisted version of object that is being updated?

Tags: php, extbase, typo3-9.x

I'm developing an Extbase extension with TYPO3 v.9.5.
When updating an object in the controller I want to compare some properties of the new with the old object before persisting the new object.

I'm confused why I'm only finding the new values.
How can I get the old ones, that are still in the DB?

Here's a code snippet of how I'm trying it currently:

```
<?php

namespace XX\Xxxxxx\Controller;

use XX\Xxxxxx\Domain\Model\Feedback;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\Inject;

class ContactController extends ActionController {
    /**
     * @Inject
     * @var XX\Xxxxxx\Domain\Repository\FeedbackRepository
     */
    protected $feedbackRepository = null;

    public function updateFeedbackAction(Feedback $feedback) {
        $oldFeedback = $this->feedbackRepository->findByUid($feedback->getUid());
        DebuggerUtility::var_dump($feedback->getState());
        // Why does this print the updated values as well? I didn't persist yet...
        DebuggerUtility::var_dump($oldFeedback->getState());
    }
}
```

To visualize: I change it from "Test..." to "Test".
[image: Test...]
[image: Test]

And after I hit save I get the following output from the `var_dump`:
[image: Same result]
But I expect "Test..." in the second dump.

Comment: What does the getState() function do? Simply take a property from the object or does it take data from the database for example?

Comment: A getter of the property "state" which is of type String, so yeah - property from the object.

Comment: Did you try do dump only one of them instead of both at the same time?

Comment: Thanks for the idea - I just tried only dumping `$oldFeedback->getState()` and it still prints the new value, not the old one...so confusing to me...

Comment: This is really weird... have you viewed the request body from your browser dev tools that your new value is the value you wanted to be? Maybe your front-end doesn't update the value correctly which leads to sending the old/default data?

Comment: In the frontend everything seems correct - the POST request has the correct new value and in the response the dump just contains the raw string, that's why I'm quite sure the problem lies in the backend. I suspect that the repository somehow doesn't load the correct object :(

Comment: ah yes, the problem is the way around, they both show the new value not the old one. My bad. Can you test your repository oldFeedback->getState() function without executing the one from $feedback->getState()? Not sure if you did that automatically when testing only one dump from my previous question. Can you also test the function from another controller function (create a new GET controller function or something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to get the old object before the action kicks in and save it in a global variable. For example:

```
 /**
 * @var Feedback $oldFeedback
 */
protected $oldFeedback = null;

public function initializeUpdateFeedbackAction() {
    // how you get the uid is up to you. This will not throw an exception 
    // if the feedback argument is missing
    $arguments = $this->request->getArguments();
    $feedbackId = $arguments['feedback']['uid'];
    $this->oldFeedback = $this->feedbackRepository->findByUid($feedbackId);
}
```

Then you can continue to do whatever you want on your function `updateFeedbackAction` and compare the two states.

Haven't test it yet, but it should work

Here is the initialize documentation: [Initialize](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/7-Controllers/1-Creating-Controllers-and-Actions.html#initializeaction)

Comment: Can you explain why the OP should do it this way instead of the current way. What behavior is happening right now that is causing the issue that you need to do it this way?

Comment: thx, this helped me solved my problem - but I had to use `clone` in order to make it work